# Going back to Main Activity when connection between client and server is lost but not when socket is closed in code

Tags: java, android, sockets

My android app is connecting with server on PC. I want it to go back to Main Activity when connection is lost. And it works when I close the server myself or when there is some kind of error. 
But the user have also ability to reconnect and while doing so in code i close the socket and connect it again. And while doing it of course connection is also lost and app goes back to Main Activity.

When I want to reconnect to server I have to close the socket and connect again because when I connect again wothout closing I am not able to send data. Closing socket stops the thread but I don't want app to go back to main Activity in this case

Here is code of my service that connects to the server:

```
public class ConnectionService extends Service {
private Socket socket;
public static PrintWriter out;
private ObjectInputStream in;
private final IBinder binder = new MyBinder();    
private Thread thread;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    ConnectionService getMyService() {
        return ConnectionService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent!=null){
        final Intent i = intent;
        final Bundle extras = i.getExtras();            
        thread= new Thread(new Listener());
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if(socket!=null) socket.close(); //here I'm losing connection and going back to Main Activity. I want to prevent that
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(extras.getString("IP"));
                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr,8998);
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                            .getOutputStream())), true);                        
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());                        
                    thread.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                        
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class Listener implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            if(Thread.interrupted()) return;
            try {
               String[] array = (String[])in.readObject();

                if(array!=null) {

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putStringArray("files",array);
                    Intent i = new Intent(ConnectionService.this,FileExplorer.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e) { //while closing socket I get this exception 
                e.printStackTrace();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectionService.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void send(String line){
    out.println(line);
}
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to close the connection, don't close the connection. Unclear what you're asking. NB a simple `break` would be a lot neater than all that messing around interrupting the thread, testing for that, etc.

Comment: When I want to reconnect to server I have to close the socket and connect again because when I connect again wothout closing I am not able to send data. Closing socket stops the thread but I don't want app to go back to main Activity in this case